# how to add index to the columns in parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am very new to database in parse.com. We have a big table about ~70 columns, and we are trying to move it to parse. I am wondering if we can add an index to some of the columns. Parse said the index is automatically added to the column, and it's called smart index. How do I know if the index is created or not, how and when it is created, or if we can force create the index.

I couldn't find it in their blog, the only thing i found out is that the index is called smart index.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your end goal a little bit more? I'm not sure smart indexing is what you think it is. And you can absolutely find it in their guides, just might not have looked hard enough? I just don't think it would be smart to override what parse does, they seem to keep things concise and logically written. How do you know if an index is written??? Simple, just look at the Parse console or your Class from Parse.com, in terms of client side they have call backs for that. I just feel your going to have to clear things up what it exactly it is your looking to do

Comment: Hi soulshined, thank you so much for the input. I was looking for if the index created or not for each column, but this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

parse database is automatic generated two key createdAt and updatedAt

when you get the parse query that time you write like ...

```
    getwishlit.addAscendingOrder(key_createdAt);
```

Comment: How createdAt and updatedAt can help for the index? If I want to query one field, I don't want the parse go through the whole db.

Comment: @AndyDong in parse database automatic generating createdAt Filed when user inserting a data and it's Date data type.